# week(NOW()) starts on Sunday Need to start on Monday

Tags: mysql

right now I have this pulling data for the current week, but the week starts on sunday, I would like the day to start on Monday how can I do this?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM form_2 WHERE week(timestamp) = week(NOW())");
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week), use `WEEK(timestamp,1)`

Comment: This indeed solved my problem. Trying to find out why som invoices where created on the wrong week if created on sundays.. And after a while.. - found this.

Answer (score 4):

You could try: `"SELECT * FROM form_2 WHERE week(timestamp - INTERVAL 1 DAY) = week(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)"`

Comment: @nos actually posted a better answer. you should probably go with their solution!

Comment: @toon81 I agree that nos solution is better for this specific question but assuming you are looking to start a week NOT on a Monday or a Sunday, your solution (with minor adjustments), solves the problem for every other day of the week. So your solution was really helpful for me. Thanks.